# Lucene integration with EclipseLink

Tags: java, lucene, eclipselink

I am trying to use Lucene with EclipseLink, and was wondering if there are any good integration libraries out there?  I have seen solar-flare, and it looks lime it might do what I want, but it's out of date (although i have an older version of EclipseLink, I am using 4.10 of Lucene) That may work, but I cant find any documentation, examples or tutorials on how to use it.

Any advice would be appreciated (I dont believe we can switch to Hibernate either)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should add more info as far as what exactly you're looking to do. As it is, your question is a bit vague and likely to get closed because of "primarily opinion based" (i.e. you're likely to start a fight over what the best tool is).

Comment: I'm wanting to use lucene to search/organize text in a database.  My understanding is, HibernateSearch, and formerly Compass, provide a seties of annotTions to make indexing fields relatively oainless.  Im wondering if that technology exists for EclipseLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ready to use Lucene via a server you can use Solr (with SolrJ)

SolJ provide to you the annotations to annotate your Pojo (look at this: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Directly_adding_POJOs_to_Solr)